# OpenCV's Python - OS X

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I get the following error while building OpenCV on OS X 10.5 (intel):

```
ld: warning in .libs/_cv_la-_cv.o, file is not of required architecture
ld: warning in .libs/_cv_la-error.o, file is not of required architecture
ld: warning in .libs/_cv_la-pyhelpers.o, file is not of required architecture
ld: warning in .libs/_cv_la-cvshadow.o, file is not of required architecture
ld: warning in ../../../cv/src/.libs/libcv.dylib, file is not of required architecture
ld: warning in /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/usr/local/lib/libcxcore.dylib, file is not of required architecture
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_fputs$UNIX2003", referenced from:
  _PySwigObject_print in _cv_la-_cv.o
  _PySwigPacked_print in _cv_la-_cv.o
  _PySwigPacked_print in _cv_la-_cv.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
lipo: can't open input file: /var/folders/Sr/Srq9N4R8Hr82xeFvW3o-uk+++TI/-Tmp-//cchT0WVX.out (No such file or directory)
make[4]: *** [_cv.la] Error 1
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

While running ./configure --without-python everything is ok. Another strange thing is that when I used Python 2.4.5 or 2.5.1 everything has built ok, the problem occured after switching to Python Framework 2.5.2

Comment: Which distribution of python are you using? Perhaps it has not been tested with OpenCV. Have you considered using macports to build python and opencv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I kind of worked it out

It needs to be compiled with python from macports or whatever. Then I need to run `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/python2.5` (this is my previous python version) and there OpenCV just works.

Answer (score 1):

It seems a little weird that it is warning about different architectures when looking for /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk while linking - can you give us some more detail about your build environment (version of XCode, GCC, Python, $PATH etc)

Alternatively, won't any of the OpenCV binaries available work for you?

Answer (score 0):

/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/usr/local/lib is just a link to /usr/local/lib
after deleting files that caused the warnings I'm getting :

```
ld: warning in .libs/_cv_la-_cv.o, file is not of required architecture
ld: warning in .libs/_cv_la-error.o, file is not of required architecture
ld: warning in .libs/_cv_la-pyhelpers.o, file is not of required architecture
ld: warning in .libs/_cv_la-cvshadow.o, file is not of required architecture
ld: warning in ../../../cv/src/.libs/libcv.dylib, file is not of required architecture
ld: warning in /Users/Pietras/opencv/cxcore/src/.libs/libcxcore.dylib, file is not of required architecture
Undefined symbols for architecture i386: ... `
```

And these files are created by make.

gcc: i686-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.0.1

$PATH:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/sw/bin:/sw/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/AVRMacPack/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
```

XCode 3 (latest)

Python 2.5.1 (r251:54869, Apr 18 2007, 22:08:04) - MacPython from python.org
(tried to downgrade and use it instead of 2.5.2, but that doesn't work anymore...)

```
which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python
```

I didn't find any Python OpenCV binaries for OS X.
I've tried to make it while setting python2.4 or 2.5 from macports as default and it compiles and installs, but when I try to import there is a bus error or Fatal Python error Interpreter not initialized (version mismatch?)
 and it quits.